# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError?

Tags: python, python-import, python-3.7

I've read a few Python relative vs. absolute import tutorials and can't figure out this `ModuleNotFound` error for the life of me.

I'm working with the following directory structure:

```
project
 |    
 +-- pseudo
 |  |  
 |  +-- __main__.py  
 |  |
 |  +-- pseudo.py
 |  |  
 |  +-- analytics_generator
 |      |
 |      +-- analytics_generator.py
 |      |
 |      +-- models
 |         |
 |         +-- blueprint.py
```

The root of the problem is that in the analytics_generator.py file, I'm trying to import SomeClass from blueprint.py.

When I execute the main function in `__main__.py`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1741, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1735, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1135, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File ".../project/pseudo/__main__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pseudo import Pseudo
  File ".../project/pseudo/pseudo.py", line 4, in <module>
    from analytics_generator.analytics_generator import AnalyticsGenerator
  File ".../project/pseudo/analytics_generator/analytics_generator.py", line 1, in <module>
    from models.blueprints import SomeClass
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'
```

I'm running the script within Pycharm and my working directory is `.../project/pseudo`

In the analytics_generator.py file, if I change the import statement to a relative import it works: `from .models.blueprints import SomeClass`.

However, using the full path doesn't:

`from pseudo.analytics_generator.models.blueprints import SomeClass` throws:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pseudo.analytics_generator'; 'pseudo' is not a package`

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you read [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)?

Answer (score 0):

The directory in which the script is being executed shouldn't need to be specified. Since you're executing `__main__.py`, the following should do:

```
from analytics_generator.models.blueprint import SomeClass
```

---

Source/Further Reading: [The Definitive Guide to Python import Statements: Absolute vs. Relative Import](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html#absolute-vs-relative-import)

> **Example Directory Structure**
>
> ```
>    test/                      # root folder
>         packA/                 # package packA
>             subA/              # subpackage subA
>                 __init__.py
>                 sa1.py
>                 sa2.py
>             __init__.py
>             a1.py
>             a2.py
>         packB/                 # package packB (implicit namespace package)
>             b1.py
>             b2.py
>         math.py
>         random.py
>         other.py
>         start.py
> ```
>
> For example, suppose we are running `start.py` which imports `a1` which in turn imports `other`, `a2`, and `sa1`. Then the import statements in `a1.py` would look as follows:
>
> - absolute imports:
>
>   ```
>     import other
>     import packA.a2
>     import packA.subA.sa1
>   ```

Note that there isn't a need to specify `import test.other` or `import test.packA.test.other` (where `test` is the directory in which the script `start.py` is being executed). The same principle should apply to your situation, [regardless of `__init__.py` or not](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html#converting-a-folder-of-scripts-into-an-importable-package-of-modules), given you're using Python 3.3 and above.

---

For posterity and completeness, I'll quote another section of the guide:

> [...] when Python runs a script, its containing folder is not considered a package.

This explains the `'pseudo' is not a package` error.

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion solved the issue, and the example you provided is very similar to the situation I'm working with. I will give the rest of the tutorial a read.

Comment: One thing that I find weird is that Pycharm doesn't validate the import statement. I get ```Unresolved reference 'analytics_generator' more... (⌘F1)``` even though the script runs without error.... @TrebledJ Do you have any experience here? More of an IDE thing so I'll read up on the Pycharm docs

Comment: @JulianMclain Hehe, yeah I get those warnings on PyCharm too, I ignore them for the most part (probably because I've only ever made/use one package in my entire history). I'll be honest—I'm only an amateur with PyCharm. :)